# OpenCV VideoCapture.Shape creates a NoneType Error

Tags: python, image, opencv, video-streaming

SO I'm watching this youtube video on creating a watermark overlay on a live video stream in Opencv and I downloaded his code and started following along but when I try to run the code I get this error:

```
line 39, in <module>
frame_h, frame_w, frame_c = frame.shape 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

I've gogogle searched the issue and all that I'm finding are issues related to image.shape not frame.shape(in this case frame = VideoCapture.read) which I believe is incorrect but I'm new to Opencv so what exactly is the issue and how can it be fixed? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

from utils import CFEVideoConf, image_resize

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

save_path = 'saved-media/watermark.mp4'
frames_per_seconds = 24
config = CFEVideoConf(cap, filepath=save_path, res='720p')
out = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path, config.video_type, frames_per_seconds, config.dims)

img_path = 'images/logo/cfe-coffee.png'
logo = cv2.imread(img_path, -1)
watermark = image_resize(logo, height=50)
#watermark = cv2.cvtColor(watermark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#watermark = cv2.cvtColor(watermark, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
watermark = cv2.cvtColor(watermark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
# grayscale watermark
# cv2.imshow('watermark', watermark)
#print(watermark.shape)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # print(frame[50, 150]) # numpy array
    # start_cord_x = 50
    # start_cord_y = 150
    # color = (255, 0, 0) #BGR 0-255 
    # stroke = 2
    # w = 100
    # h = 200
    # end_cord_x = start_cord_x + w
    # end_cord_y = start_cord_y + h
    # cv2.rectangle(frame, (start_cord_x, start_cord_y), (end_cord_x, end_cord_y), color, stroke)
    # print(frame[start_cord_x:end_cord_x, start_cord_y:end_cord_y])

    frame_h, frame_w, frame_c = frame.shape
    #print(frame.shape)

    # overlay with 4 channels BGR and Alpha
    overlay = np.zeros((frame_h, frame_w, 4), dtype='uint8')
    #overlay[100:250, 100:125] = (255, 255, 0, 1) # B, G, R, A
    #overlay[100:250, 150:255] = (0, 255, 0, 1) # B, G, R, A
    #overlay[start_y:end_y, start_x:end_x] = (B, G, R, A)
    #cv2.imshow("overlay", overlay)
    watermark_h, watermark_w, watermark_c = watermark.shape
    for i in range(0, watermark_h):
        for j in range(0, watermark_w):
            #print(watermark[i,j])
            if watermark[i,j][3] != 0:
                #watermark[i, j] # RBGA
                offset = 10
                h_offset = frame_h - watermark_h - offset
                w_offset = frame_w - watermark_w - offset
                overlay[h_offset + i, w_offset+ j] = watermark[i,j]

    cv2.addWeighted(overlay, 0.25, frame, 1.0, 0, frame)



    #frame.addimage(watermark)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
    out.write(frame)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The error implies that `frame` is `None`, which most likely means that `cap.read()` did not capture any image. Assert that `ret` is true before reading the frame. If `ret` is false, that means there is something wrong with how `cap` is reading from your video source.

Comment: Thanks I added: 

if (cap.isOpened()== False): 
  print("Error opening video")
    
    while(cap.isOpened()):
  # Capture frame-by-frame
  ret, frame = cap.read()
  if ret == True: 

  Now their is no error, my webcam turns on, but nothing else is happening. I'm really lost now, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

cap is an object of cv2 and is returned by cv2.VideoCapture. It returns an object even if it does not get any video. So check the source, in this case default source, which generally is web camera.